# Can I use the other ports on my ONT?

Tags: optical-network-terminal

So my ONT has 4 ports. I tried plugging in another router to LAN2, but the ONT/LAN2 light never even came on.

Is this something that I should be able to use, or would it require ISP activation or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this something that I should be able to use, or would it require ISP activation or something?* (Meaning additional ports on your ONT for Internet)

No, this is not something you should be able to use in most cases.

Your ISP most likely will have all ports on your ONT disabled except the one you are using for your subscribed service(s). In most cases I have seen, providers only enable one port per service. A common use would be Port 1 for Internet, Port 2 for IPTV, and additional ports may be used for dedicated VoIP service, security/surveillance services, off-premise network extensions, or other dedicated services.

In general, most ISP's only allow ONE device to be connected to your Internet connection from their perspective, such as a single router which you would then connect your various devices to.

Also, in some cases an ONT provides service to more than individual or service location, meaning Port 1 may be yours, while Port 2 is intended for an adjacent suite or apartment.

Although it would be unusual, if your use case fits the ISP's T&C of service, they may activate the 2nd or additional ports for your use acting essentially like a switch on the public side of the connection for additional connections to the public Internet, but again this would depend on your ISP's policies but be aware you may incur an additional monthly service charge and/or a one-time setup fee.

Although this answer has no links to online sources, it comes from 30 years of experience in the telecommunications industry and I currently work as a network engineer for a multi-service provider with a fiber network serving over 25 exchanges with telephone, IPTV, Internet, and various other services.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. That is a very comprehensive and useful answer.